# Any non-valid user to the application can access the PDF help file by entering its absolute URL directly into the browser ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-authorization

I have an ASP.net application with target framework 3.5. I have create a help file named UserGuide.pdf and provided a menu item on the page. when user clicks the help menu this PDF file is opening in the new tab of the browser. I use Windows Authentication for the same application.

My problem is, the .pdf file can be accessed directly by using the URL, and I have to stop it somehow. What is a quick way to do it?

Comment: What's the difference between clicking a link to the pdf and typing the address manually? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Make a generic handler and serve the file from there.

Comment: @Esko: when I am clicking the menu, i am logged into the application as a valid user. when I am using the URL i dont need to login the application. So i want to stop loading the file if i am not logged into the application.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably other ways...
Since you already using user based authorization...it should be a snap.
But read about it an learn what all is involved [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/user-based-authorization-csr)

The web.config goes into the same folder as the documents...so you could possibly end up with several web.configs.

It will look something like this...again read the documentation.
(Using Admin role for example)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- this would be for just that one file -->
  <location path="UserGuid.PDF">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <!-- this would be for whole directory -->
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

**Note...if any mistakes are present...please feel free to correct.